# DJango query based on value between two records

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table of records that has a name and a value.  The table is arranged like this:

```
ID CLASS   MINIMUM
1  classA  1
2  classB  6
3  classC  10
4  classD  25
```

if given a number I am looking for the ID of the record under but closest to that number.
For example, if I give you a 5, the system returns a 1.  If I give you a 11, the system returns a 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
rand_number = 10 #Or any random number
min_obj = MyModel.objects.filter(minimum__lte=rand_number).order_by('-minimum').first()
id = min_obj.id if min_obj else None
```

Basically, order the column named `minimum` (or whatever) in descending order, and and get the first record - Note `first()` works only for django >= 1.6, and fetch the ID

Comment: Absolutely Perfect.  Thank you so much.